# Changing mouse cursor using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm using this code to change the mouse cursor to progress when i'm calling some Ajax function :

```
$('html,body').css('cursor', 'progress');
```

It works BUT at least on Chrome on Mac, i can only see the cursor change after i move the mouse a bit. If i don't move the mouse, i won't see change. I call this function right after i click on a button, so the mouse cursor will be on a button. The issue seems to be related to the fact a button is behind the mouse cursor.

I don't know if this problem happen on another browsers or OS. My current user agent :

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.33 Safari/537.36

Is there a way to workaround this issue, so i can see the cursor changing right after i execute the command ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide your code? Alternatively, you could create a new class, which you add to `html, body` with `addClass()`, after calling the Ajax function. Maybe this could help.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? Have you tried on other browsers?

Comment: @Rastalamm I've just edited the question with my user agent.

Comment: @rojadesign The only code i need to test the issue is the one i provided. If i just execute this code, the mouse cursos won't change until i move it.

Comment: @delphirules I use Chrome on Windows 10 and have just the same issue. Edit: `addClass()` has the same issue.